# Change css attribute at time

Tags: css, date, time

I would like that on a specific date and time,
a div in my site changes some attributes of css.

Ex.

On 15/03/16  time 08:32 PM.

```
#xxx {colour: red;}
```

change to

```
#xxx {coulour: blue;}
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks 
Mauro

Comment: via JS set an Interval with a `60000` msec delay (1 min.) and if the `getHours()` and `getMinutes()` return `8` and `32` (same for data) of your local time then apply a class to the element containing that message. Just to give you roughly the idea.

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done with pure CSS.

It can be done with any server-side language and/or JavaScript.